# Gap analysis on recurrent value which is added once every month

Tags: missing-data

I need little help on a challenge that I have to determine on which month I have a missing recurrent value record. In short, the story is the following: Let say that I have a table e.g.

```
customer_charge    (id, charge_id,  from_date,   to_date ,  recurrent_value)
                   ( 1,     10   , 01.01.2020, 31.01.2020,         15      )
                   ( 2,     23   , 01.01.2020, 31.01.2020,          0      )
                   ( 3,     10   , 01.02.2020, 29.02.2020,          0      )
                   ( 4,     23   , 01.02.2020, 29.02.2020,         15      )
                   ( 5,     10   , 01.03.2020, 31.03.2020,          0      )
                   ( 6,     10   , 01.04.2020, 30.04.2020,         15      )
```

I have also another table details as

```
details    (id, cust_id, charge_id,       charge_date,    recurrent_value,         period        ) 
           ( 1,   100  ,     10   ,  01.01.2020 03:12:10,        15      ,  01.01.2020-31.01.2020)
           ( 2,   100  ,     10   ,  01.04.2020 02:54:12,        15      ,  01.04.2020-30.04.2020)
           ( 3,   200  ,     23   ,  01.02.2020 02:22:25,        15      ,  01.02.2020-29.02.2020)
```

Those recurrent values in customer_charge table are added once a month (following calendar length as period). There is trigger logic which checks the value if it's positive (value > 0) -> insert a new record in details table. The expected result is that, for every customer to see the missing recurrent values per month. So the result be something like:

```
cust_id, month, recurrent_value
  100  , 'FEB',         0
  100  , 'MAR',         0
  200  , 'JAN',         0
```

There is a 3rd table which link the customer_charge.charge_id with details.cust_id, so the system knows for which customer is the respective recurrent_value

Comment: You have not actually asked a question.

Comment: My question here is - how can I retrieve all records where the value in details table is missing ?